# How to archive multiple icon changes for Bootstrap collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I click on Root Documents 1 and Root Documents 2 the icon should be changed “glyphicon-triangle-bottom” to “glyphicon-triangle-right”.

In child list of Root Documents 1 and Root Documents 2 the icon should be changed on “glyphicon-triangle-right” to “glyphicon-triangle-bottom”.

The scripts below was conflicted in child list

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-right").first().removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-right").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom").first().removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-right");
});
```

Reference Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/3150/

How archive the same without conflict.
Kindly advice me is really appreciated.

Comment: what you want actually ??

Comment: @YoYo : i want to change glypicon for "collapse" and "collapse in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-right')) {
$(this).removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-right").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
} else {
$(this).removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-right");
}
});
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/7aseco56/